# selection of data from a sqlite3 table between two dates

Tags: python-3.x

I created a python code for the selection between two dates of the data contained in a sqlite3 table.

***first code :***

```
def select_by_dates (self):

try :

    conn = sqlite3.connect ('correction.db')
    curseur=conn.cursor()

    curseur.execute("SELECT * FROM correction_loc35R  where  date_correction between '01-12-2019' AND '28-12-2019' ORDER BY date_correction DESC")

    liste_select_by_dates_correction=c.fetchall()
    nbr_rows=len(liste_select_by_dates_correction)

    if nbr_rows != 0 :

        # set row count
        self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.setRowCount(nbr_rows)

        for nb in range(nbr_rows):
            for nombre in range(10):
            self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.setItem(nb,nombre, QTableWidgetItem(liste_select_by_dates_correction[nb][nombre]))

        self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.resizeColumnsToContents()        

    conn.commit()
    curseur.close()
    conn.close()
    else :
        print("OK")

    except :
        print("error")
```

***second code :***

```
def select_by_dates (self):

start_date ='01-12-2019'             
end_date = '28-12-2019'

try :

    conn = sqlite3.connect ('correction.db')
    curseur=conn.cursor()

    curseur.execute("SELECT * FROM correction_loc35R  where  date_correction between start_date AND end_date ORDER BY date_correction DESC")


    liste_select_by_dates_correction=c.fetchall()
    nbr_rows=len(liste_select_by_dates_correction)

    if nbr_rows != 0 :

        # set row count
        self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.setRowCount(nbr_rows)

        for nb in range(nbr_rows):
            for nombre in range(10):
            self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.setItem(nb,nombre, QTableWidgetItem(liste_select_by_dates_correction[nb][nombre]))

        self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction.resizeColumnsToContents()        

    conn.commit()
    curseur.close()
    conn.close()
    else :
        print("OK")

    except :
        print("error")
```

the column "date_correction" of the table "correction_loc35R" is of the form 'TEXT'.

a "search" button has been associated with this "select_by_dates" function.

for the first code, if I click on the search button; I have a display of the data on the tablewidget "tableWidget_select_by_dates_correction"; but for the second code, it doesn't work.
the two codes are almost similar, and yet I have two different results

Answer (score 0):

I modify the line :

```
curseur.execute("SELECT * FROM correction_loc35R  where  date_correction between start_date AND end_date ORDER BY date_correction DESC")
```

by this comand lines :

```
strDbSQL = ''
strDbSQL += 'SELECT * '
strDbSQL += '  FROM correction_loc35R '
strDbSQL += ' WHERE date_correction between '
strDbSQL += date_debut_cev_loc35R.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
strDbSQL += '   AND '
strDbSQL += date_fin_cev_loc35R.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
strDbSQL += ' ORDER BY date_correction DESC'

c=curseur.execute(strDbSQL)
```

but it has no effect; always the same result